# C#: ¿Por qué al convertir un documento a bytes y después volverlo a convertir a archivo el nuevo archivo pesa el doble?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy en desarrollo de un sistema, y una de las tareas que requiero para el mismo es hacer la transferencia e cualquier tipo de archivo. Para poder hacer esto, un cliente especifica el archivo que se quiere transmitir y se genera un archivo con un encabezado, un boundary y posteriormente viene el "cuerpo" del archivo, donde viene el archivo a transferirse.
Para hacer ésto, todos los archivos se deben "convertir" a bytes y hacer la copia fiel a un nuevo archivo temporal, solo de los bytes correspondientes al cuerpo (que es el archivo).

El problema que tengo hasta ahora, es que si es una imagen, la imagen no se puede ver, y el archivo temporal que se genera, con respecto al original, llega a pesar más del doble (debería pesar lo mismo).

Hice pruebas y corroboré que la lectura solo se hiciera una vez, y en efecto, solo se realiza una vez.

Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
long tamano = request.ContentLength64;//obtengo el tamaño del archivo en bytes
string contentType = request.Headers.Get("content-Type");
string boundary = contentType.Split('=')[1];//divido la cadena que contiene el boundary (delimitador) para saber de donde a donde leer
var stream = request.InputStream;
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);//creo el stream para realizar la lectura y escritura.

string linea1 = sr.ReadLine();//esto no se debe escribir en el documento
    tamano = tamano - linea1.Length;

    linea1 = sr.ReadLine();//esto no se debe escribir en el documento
    tamano = tamano - linea1.Length;

    linea1 = sr.ReadLine();//esto no se debe escribir en el documento
    tamano = tamano - linea1.Length;

    if (linea1 != "\r\n")//verificamos si hay un salto de linea
    {

        linea1 = sr.ReadLine();
        tamano = tamano - linea1.Length;
    }

    string prelinea = sr.ReadLine();
    tamano = tamano - prelinea.Length;

    long suma = 0;
    int contador = 0;

    System.Console.WriteLine("Datos a escribir: {0}",tamano);//verifico cuantos datos debo escribir (del archivo original)
    while (tamano > 0)
    {
        linea1 = sr.ReadLine();
        tamano = tamano - linea1.Length;
        if (prelinea.Contains(boundary))
        {
            contador++;
            Console.WriteLine(contador);
        }

        if (linea1.Contains(boundary))
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prelinea + System.Environment.NewLine);//convierto la linea a bytes y agrego un salto de linea, de lo contrario todo se escribe en una sola linea
            suma += data.Length;
            sfile.Write(data,0,data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Suma total de datos escritos: {0}", suma);
            Console.WriteLine("Valor Final del contador {0}",contador);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prelinea + System.Environment.NewLine);
            //Console.WriteLine(data.Length);
            //Console.WriteLine(data);
            suma += data.Length;
            sfile.Write(data,0,data.Length);
            prelinea = linea1;
        }
    }
    sfile.Close();
    sfile.Dispose();
}
finally
{
    stream.Close();
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

Leo el archivo linea por linea, lo convierto a bytes, y lo escribo al documento temporal. Sin embargo, el archivo queda no leible y e peso es más del doble.

Un ejemplo del archivo a leer es el siguiente:

```
--f7H1ZivE3w_uBcVCfUEUaj9ROwjDZx6v9f4lcN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Saludo.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Archivo de prueba
Saludos
--f7H1ZivE3w_uBcVCfUEUaj9ROwjDZx6v9f4lcN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="archivo"

{"nombre":"Saludo.txt","id":null,"idDirectorio":"ID123456","tamano":26,"idPropietario":null,"creado":null,"modificado":null,"estado":0,"tipoProcesamiento":0}
--f7H1ZivE3w_uBcVCfUEUaj9ROwjDZx6v9f4lcN--
```

El texto que viene después de los -- es el delimitador y las lineas:
Archivo de prueba
Saludos

son las que debo rescatar, ya que estas un documento de texto que tiene ese contenido. Pero repito, puede ser cualquier tipo de archivo (una imagen, una canción, un video, etc) y por ello debo llevarlo a bytes y no manejarlo como texto.

Si alguien pudiera darme una pista, le agradecería demasiado.

Comment: El código es un poco raro, pero para empezar deberías tambien pegar el código en el que generas los datos a trasmitir con tu cabecera etc. ya que es posible que el problema venga de ahi

Comment: ¿Es un fichero binario o de texto? Si es de texto, ¿cuál es el encoding?

Comment: El archivo, como se menciona, puede ser de cualquier tipo, el cual debe convertirse en bytes, viene inmerso en el archivo que acabo de colocar y posteriormente obtener solo los bytes correspondientes al archivo, ignorando la cabecera y el json que se genera.